# executing init and fini

Tags: c, linux, gcc, elf

I just read about [init and fini sections](http://l4u-00.jinr.ru/usoft/WWW/www_debian.org/Documentation/elf/node3.html) in ELF files and gave it a try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  puts("main");
  return 0;
}

void init(){
  puts("init");
}
void fini(){
  puts("fini");
}
```

If I do `gcc -Wl,-init,init -Wl,-fini,fini foo.c` and run the result the "init" part is not printed:

```
$ ./a.out
main
fini
```

Did the init part not run, or was it not able to print somehow?

Is there a any "official" documentation about the init/fini stuff?

`man ld` says:

```
 -init=name
     When creating an ELF executable or shared object, call
     NAME when the executable or shared object is loaded, by
     setting DT_INIT to the address of the function.  By
     default, the linker uses "_init" as the function to call.
```

Shouldn't that mean, that it would be enough to name the init function `_init`? (If I do gcc complains about multiple definition.)

Comment: This is weird... regarding your first question - my GDB shows that the init function does not run at all.

Comment: It's quite possible that the unit section runs before the standard library is initialized enough for puts to work. Why don't you try something with no dependencies, like setting a global variable, to see if the unit function actually runs.

Comment: The way you did, works for share library, not for program which gets a default _init and a default _fini, already.

Answer (score 22):

Don't do that; let your compiler and linker fill in the sections as they see fit.

Instead, mark your functions with the appropriate [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes), so that the compiler and linker will put them in the correct sections.

For example,

```
static void before_main(void) __attribute__((constructor));
static void after_main(void) __attribute__((destructor));

static void before_main(void)
{
    /* This is run before main() */
}

static void after_main(void)
{
    /* This is run after main() returns (or exit() is called) */
}
```

You can also assign a priority (say, `__attribute__((constructor (300)))`), an integer between 101 and 65535, inclusive, with functions having a smaller priority number run first.

Note that for illustration, I marked the functions `static`. That is, the functions won't be visible outside the file scope. The functions do not need to be exported symbols to be automatically called.

---

For testing, I suggest saving the following in a separate file, say `tructor.c`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

static int outfd = -1;

static void wrout(const char *const string)
{
    if (string && *string && outfd != -1) {
        const char       *p = string;
        const char *const q = string + strlen(string);

        while (p < q) {
            ssize_t n = write(outfd, p, (size_t)(q - p));
            if (n > (ssize_t)0)
                p += n;
            else
            if (n != (ssize_t)-1 || errno != EINTR)
                break;
        }
    }
}

void before_main(void) __attribute__((constructor (101)));
void before_main(void)
{
    int saved_errno = errno;

    /* This is run before main() */
    outfd = dup(STDERR_FILENO);
    wrout("Before main()\n");

    errno = saved_errno;
}

static void after_main(void) __attribute__((destructor (65535)));
static void after_main(void)
{
    int saved_errno = errno;

    /* This is run after main() returns (or exit() is called) */
    wrout("After main()\n");

    errno = saved_errno;
}
```

so you can compile and link it as part of any program or library. To compile it as a shared library, use e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -shared tructor.c -Wl,-soname,libtructor.so -o libtructor.so
```

and you can interpose it into any dynamically linked command or binary using

```
LD_PRELOAD=./libtructor.so some-command-or-binary
```

The functions keep `errno` unchanged, although it should not matter in practice, and use the low-level `write()` syscall to output the messages to standard error. The initial standard error is duplicated to a new descriptor, because in many instances, the standard error itself gets closed before the last global destructor -- our destructor here -- gets run.

(Some paranoid binaries, typically security sensitive ones, close all descriptors they don't know about, so you *might* not see the `After main()` message in all cases.)

Comment: How exactly do those funktion attributes work? Does the compiler generate individual code for the init/fini sections? But as far as I understood the code is linked from a different file (crti.o).

Comment: @michas Fundamentally, those attributes expose within the C language exactly the same mechanism that allows C++ global objects to be constructed at initialization time. Both C++ constructors and `__attribute__((constructor))` -annotated C functions are simply code that is called "before `main`", so that (in the former case) the objects are ready to use by the time `main` begins.

Comment: @michas: Yes, `crti.o` provides the code the GNU C library needs in the ELF `_init` and `_fini` sections. It depends on the specific ABI used (x86, x86-64, ARM variants, etc.) exactly how the marked functions get called. On x86-64, for example, I believe the function addresses are listed in the `.init_array` and `.fini_array` sections instead (`__frame_dummy_init_array_entry` and ` __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry` symbols, respectively).

Comment: @NominalAnimal - I agree that constructor/destructor attributes should be used, but can you explain why -init did not work? (just to satisfy my curiosity... :) )

Comment: @MByD: As [4566976](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32701700/1475978) wrote, `ld` ignores the `-init` option completely. I just verified it with GCC 4.8.4 and binutils 2.24.

Comment: @MByD: Use `readelf -d binary` to list the dynamic symbols in a binary. If linker option `-init` did anything, you'd see the address for the `INIT` symbol in the above list differ (point to the named symbol, instead of the C library `_init` function). It does not, on the aforementioned versions, on x86-64. `ld` option `-fini` changes the address of the dynamic symbol `FINI`. This means that the `_fini()` from `crti.o` gets replaced by your own function. (Which is okay on x86-64, because `_fini()` doesn't really do anything on that architecture.)

Answer (score 9):

It is not a bug in `ld` but in the glibc startup code for the main executable. For shared objects the function set by the `-init` option is called.

---

[This](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commitdiff;h=3dbf70a2184b98af04dfec550fec9ae1a804bdb0) is the commit to `ld` adding the options `-init` and `-fini`.

---

The `_init` function of the program isn't called from file [`glibc-2.21/elf/dl-init.c:58`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=elf/dl-init.c;h=2f85731ff3a716a18c5c704313d12b85efe92410;hb=4e42b5b8f89f0e288e68be7ad70f9525aebc2cff#l58) by the `DT_INIT` entry by the dynamic linker, but called from `__libc_csu_init` in file [`glibc-2.21/csu/elf-init.c:83`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=csu/elf-init.c;h=a7e534da622a5ee5ab26477b2363d300232dbc79;hb=4e42b5b8f89f0e288e68be7ad70f9525aebc2cff#l83) by the main executable.

That is, the function pointer in `DT_INIT` of the program is ignored by the startup.

If you compile with `-static`, `fini` isn't called, too.

`DT_INIT` and `DT_FINI` should definitely not be used, because they are [old-style, see line 255](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=elf/dl-fini.c;h=6cfe6519c4cf97ba9ad9e0fdb11d2efb97dc2284;hb=4e42b5b8f89f0e288e68be7ad70f9525aebc2cff#l255).

The following works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void preinit(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
    puts(__FUNCTION__);
}

static void init(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
    puts(__FUNCTION__);
}

static void fini(void) {
    puts(__FUNCTION__);
}


__attribute__((section(".preinit_array"), used)) static typeof(preinit) *preinit_p = preinit;
__attribute__((section(".init_array"), used)) static typeof(init) *init_p = init;
__attribute__((section(".fini_array"), used)) static typeof(fini) *fini_p = fini;

int main(void) {
    puts(__FUNCTION__);
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall a.c
$ ./a.out
preinit
init
main
fini
$
```

Comment: In this case it would be a bug in either the man page or ld. Or is there a good reason to ignore it in this case?

Comment: @4566976 - any documentation for this?

Comment: ld does not complain about an unknown fini name, but fini nevertheless works.

Comment: The init section *is* run! You can verify by [adding a bit of assembler](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Calling_A_Function_At_ELF_Shared_Library_Load_Time.shtml).

Comment: @michas Yes, but the function pointer in `DT_INIT` of the elf executable is ignored by the dynamic linker and the clib initialization.

Comment: if you have `.so` constructor with name `init`, it's not run, but when change to name other `init`, such as `test_init`, it works. Tested with gcc 4.1.2

Comment: `-init` and `-fini` `ld` options works, but this prevent the methods from being static.