# What operations are unsafe before __libc_init_array is invoked?

Tags: libc

I want to run some code before `main` begins, and before constructors for static variables run. I can do with with code [like this (ideone)](https://ideone.com/rAvPlz)

```
extern "C" {
    static void do_my_pre_init(void) {
        // something
    }
    __attribute__ ((section (".preinit_array"))) void(*p_init)(void) = &do_my_pre_init;
}
```

Are there any language features that will not work correctly when executed in this function, due to `_init` and `.init_array` not yet having been executed?

Or is it only user code that should be hooking into this mechanism?

---

#### Some background on `__libc_init_array`

The source for a  [typical `__libc_init_array`](http://static.grumpycoder.net/pixel/uC-sdk-doc/initfini_8c_source.html) is something like:

```
static void __libc_init_array() {
    size_t count, i;

    count = __preinit_array_end - __preinit_array_start;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        __preinit_array_start[i]();

    _init();

    count = __init_array_end - __init_array_start;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        __init_array_start[i]();
}
```

Where the `__...` symbols come from a linker script containing

```
. = ALIGN(4);
__preinit_array_start = .;
KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
__preinit_array_end = .;

. = ALIGN(4);
__init_array_start = .;
KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
KEEP (*(.init_array))
__init_array_end = .;
```

Comment: i guess using `attribute constructor` is no use in your case ?

Comment: @Burns: Does that place it in `.init_array` instead?

Comment: According to this comment from `Nominal Animal` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700494/executing-init-and-fini, using the `attribute constructor` would add the function in the .init_array, and it depends of the ABI; if you're on x86, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any language features that will not work correctly when executed in this function, due to _init and .init_array not yet having been executed?

This question is *impossible* to answer in general, because the language itself has no concept of `.preinit_array`, or `_init`, or `.init_array`. All of these concepts are *implementation* details for a *particular* system.

In reality, you aren't guaranteed to have *anything* work at all. Things as simple as `malloc` may not work (e.g. because the `malloc` subsystem itself may be using `.preinit_array` to initialize itself).

In practice, using dynamic linking on a GLIBC-based platform most everything will work (because `libc.so.6` initializes itself long before the first instruction of the main executable runs).

For fully-static executable, all bets are off.

For non-GLIBC platform, you'll need to look into specifics of that platform (and you are very unlikely to find any guarantees).

Update:

> Can I make function calls,

Function calls need no setup with fully-static linking, and need dynamic loader to have initialized in dynamic linking case. No dynamic loader will start executing code in the application before it has fully initialized itself, so function calls should be safe.

> assign structs

In `C`, at best, this is a few instructions. At worst, this is a call to `memcpy` or `memset`. That should be safe.

> use array initializers.

This is just a special case of struct assignment, so should be safe.

Comment: I guess by language feature I'm excluding any builtin functions. Can I make function calls, assign structs, use array initializers, etc. But you make a good point about this being an implementation detail.