# Destruction of structures (freeing memory)

Tags: c, free

Whenever you write a destructor for a user defined structure, do you try to dive into the structure and free as much as possible, or do you instead just free the structure itself and expect the caller to be careful about memory leaks.

I can think of pros and cons to both approaches. Is there a standard community accepted way of writing destructor?

**Toy Example**

```c
struct node {
    int *ptr;
    int num;
}
```

```c
void node_free(struct node *n) {
    /* Would you include this? */
    if (n->ptr != NULL) free(n->ptr);
    free(n);
}
```

**Scenario that raised the question**

In a graph algorithm, I want to be able to insert vertex structures into several lists at once. I created a wrapper structure that points to a vertex, and I can then insert these wrapper structures into lists. When I construct the wrapper, I pass a pointer to a vertex structure. When I destruct the wrapper, I can't destruct the vertex structure as well. So that's the scenario that made me ask this question: Is there a standard approach to writing destructors that allos the programmer not to worry about these details?

Comment: How can you expect "the caller to be careful about memory leaks" of your structure's internal members, which they might not have access, or at least `free()`ing access, to? Why should they have to figure out what they do or do not need to delete, instead of you just doing it for them? The clear answer is that you should deallocate things you allocate. The rest is too broad.

Comment: The destructor should take care of freeing the complete structure, any other approach looks crazy to me.

Comment: what do you mean by `..caller to be..`?

Comment: `if (n->ptr != NULL) free(ptr);` - Should that be `free(n->ptr);`. Will work even if `n->ptr` is NULL

Answer (score 5):

The main interest in having custom destructor functions for custom structs is precisely this : making sure every allocated part of the struct is freed at the same time. The struct user is supposed to allocate it and start using it then destroy it when it's not of any use anymore.

so short answer : **yes**

Answer (score 4):

*Edit to address question in comments:*
*...Can you summarize the point about symmetry between what the constructor allocates and what the destructor frees at the top of your answer...*

Several comments bring up Constructors and Destructors adjacent to references of symmetry.  Any programming language can implement the concept called   *[Constructor & Destructor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm)*. However, these terms are more commonly used in the context of object oriented languages, such as C++ for example, where they are member functions within a class designed to create, initialize and destroy objects and memory within the class they are a part of.  This implementation is unique to object oriented programming. But because `C` is not an object oriented language the implementation of constructors/destructor pairs will be different.  *[C++'s language-enforced Constructor/Destructor symmetry](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines)* is not an inherent feature in `C`, and although there are examples in `C` where a form of symmetry *is mirrored* in resource acquire/release function pairs, eg. `fopen`/`fclose`, symmetry is not enforced the same way.

While I did not include the same *level* of symmetry in the answer I posted here, (i.e. the argument lists are not the same between the two functions.) Some symmetry exists.  The `createTestStruct` and `freeTestStruct` functions were designed in similar fashion to *[the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/537267/645128)*, to ensure that all resources created using `createTestStruct` will be released and cleaned up by calling `freeTestStruct`.

*original answer*
If you have a `struct *` type, and that type also has member pointers, then runtime memory allocation would best be done using a callable method, and along with providing that method, another method should be provided to `free` all the memory that is created.  For example, if you have this:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t bufSize;
    char *buf;
}TEST;
```

It would be much easier for the calling function to have methods to create and *destroy* (or free) what was created...

For example, the following prototypes would be useful:

```
TEST * createTestStruct(int instances, size_t Bufsize);
void freeTestStruct(TEST *test, int instances);
```

Example usage:

```
int main(void)
{
    TEST *test = createTestStruct(10, 80);//creates instance of test, and pointer members 10 buf, each with space for 80 char

    // use test

    freeTestStruct(test, 10);//frees all 10 instances of test and buf
   return 0;
}

TEST * createTestStruct(int instances, size_t size)
{
    int i;
    TEST *test = calloc(instances, sizeof(*test));
    if(test)
    {
        for(i=0;i<instances;i++)
        {
            test[i].size = size;
            test[i].buf = calloc(test[i].size, 1);
        }
    }
    return test;
}

void freeTestStruct(TEST *test, int instances)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<instances;i++)
    {
        free(test[i].buf);
    }
    free(test);
}
```

Comment: Yup. It's simple symmetry. If your constructor allocates something, your destructor should deallocate it. Don't expect users to guess whether they need to do it... :-S

Comment: @underscore_d This comment makes sense. The destructor should free only what the corresponding constructor has allocated then?

Comment: Yes, and why would it _not_ do that? Otherwise a user cannot know (a) whether or not some pointer in the structure refers to dynamically allocated memory and (b) if it does, whether or not you expect them to free it, when you could simply do that for them, as the implementor of the structure with full knowledge on what its internals mean. The alternative would be to add tonnes of documentation explaining that the user has to free stuff that you allocated, but then why would you make them do that? Plus, they just would not and then file bugs with you. ;-)

Comment: @underscore_d The symmetry makes the most sense. Yet the following scenario raised the question in the first place, and it still bugs me a little: I am writing a graph algorithm where I want to insert vertices into several lists at once. So I created a wrapper structure that points to a vertex structure. When I free a wrapper, I can't free the vertex at the same time, as that would cause bugs. Since I can't do that, I came to wonder if there a standard approach to writing destructors that allows programmers to not worry about such details.

Comment: @RayaneCTX It could help to flesh out your question with more info on the specific scenario. Otherwise, you might get answers that are more general than you want. I suspect that the same answer applies in either case, though.

Comment: `freeTestStruct` should not need the `instances` parameter. The `TEST` struct should be self contained. I retracted my upvote because of this.

Comment: Yeah, I guess having a macro to generally allocated/free `n` objects of type `T` is better than baking that into the constructor/destructors for no apparent reason. For example, GLib provides this, in addition to an entire object system.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - `instances` _is_ needed (at least for this implementation).  For each call to `malloc`,` calloc`, there needs to be a corresponding call to free.  Freeing only the `test` object, does not free memory created for each of the `instances` of `buf` members.

Comment: Yes, of course, but the design is wrong. A destructor shouldn't have any other parameter than the pointer to the object to be destructed. Just like in C++ destructors have no parameter.

Comment: @ryyker That has no apparent relation to the debate over whether you should provide API to construct/destruct a number of instances. I think a macro that takes a type and a number would make more sense, then pass a pointer to a constructor/destructor function and a count. Don't reinvent the wheel in every type's own pair of functions.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - I will grant you that on the cuff I wrote this for illustration of concept. (It is not a perfect design).

Comment: @ryyker Can you summarize the point about symmetry between what the constructor allocates and what the destructor frees at the top of your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @underscore_d - _don't reinvent the wheel_.  I am not sure what that means.  The calling function determines how many instances of `TEST` will be created. (can be done in one call to calloc).  But for each instance of `TEST`, memory for the member `buf` will also be created. (requires 1 calloc per)  How will the freeing function know how many instances of buf to `free()` without telling it in the argument list?  (I've already owned that this design could be better, but for illustration it does demonstrate the benefit of using a method instead of having the calling function clean up memory.

Comment: @ryyker As I see it, our point is that in our opinion, your allocation and deallocation functions should only create 1 instance, and let the user or a more generic macro handle creating or destroying 1 * N instances.

Comment: @underscore_d - _our point is that in our opinion..._  How many of you exactly are there?  :)  Seriously though.  I will not argue with your opinion.  But in my experience, there are times when argument lists (well documented in the preceding comment block) in `create` and `free` functions do not have to be the same.

Comment: I meant me and @Jabberwocky of course. And the point as I see it wasn't that the argument lists have to be the same, but that they should just create/free a single instance, and that creation/freeing of multiple instances is a detail for the user.

Comment: @RayaneCTX - Per your comment I have edited in a comment about symmetry, however it is kind of orthogonal to my answer. I did not design the same symmetry into my illustration code as what I believe some of the comments are encouraging. That would go beyond the scope of what I was attempting to convey.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer destructors that do not free the structure itself, just the contents. This is so that the destructor can also be used on instances that must not be freed, for example fields of other structures, automatic variables and array elements.
If we were to provide only a routine that freed the instance along with the contents, how is the user to empty, for example, an automatic variable?

For example we could have

```
typedef struct { int n, nA; int* v; } ivT;
typedef struct { ivT is; ivT js; } egT;
```

and provide

```
ivT* ivEmpty( ivT* iv)
{ if ( iv) { free( iv->v); memset( iv, 0, sizeof *iv); }
  return iv;
}
egT* egEmpty( egT* eg)
{ if ( eg) 
  {  ivEmpty( &eg->is); ivEmpty( &eg->js);
     memset( eg, 0, sizeof *eg); 
  }  
  return eg;
}
```

we could also provide a destructor that does free the structure itself, for example

```
egT* egFree( egT* eg)
{  return (free( egEmpty( eg)), NULL);
}
```

Comment: Not a bad point, but then again, C object systems often use opaque types, so those can only be dynamically allocated anyway.